# How do we derive the components of the magnetic vector potential from a known magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, accelerator-physics

The magnetic field is

$\vec{B}(r,\theta)=B_{0} \cdot[1+\mu(r)] \cdot [1+f(r,\theta)]\hat{e}_{z}$

where $f(r, \theta)=\sum_{n}\left[a_{n}(r) \cos n \theta+b_{n}(r) \sin n \theta\right]$, and $\mu(r)$ is a function of $r$.

The magnetic vector potential $\vec{A}=A_{\gamma} \hat{e}_{y}+A_{0} \hat{e}_{\theta}$

How do we introduce the expressions for these two components as:

$A_{r}(r, \theta)=B_{0} \cdot r \cdot(1+\mu(r)) \cdot F(r, \theta)$

$A_{\theta}(r, \theta)=-\frac{1}{2} B_{0} \cdot r \cdot(1+U(r))$

where

$U(r)=\frac{2}{r^{2}} \int_{0}^{r} r^{\prime} \mu\left(r^{\prime}\right) \mathrm{d} r^{\prime}$
and $F(r, \theta)=\sum_{n}\left[\frac{a_{n}(r)}{n} \sin n \theta-\frac{b_{n}(r)}{n} \cos n \theta\right]$?

Comment: Which co-ordinate system are you using- spherical or cylindrical?

Comment: Cylindrical co-ordinate system.

Comment: Usually for solving EM potentials ($\phi,\vec{A}$), you need to first fix a gauge, since electric and magnetic fields are gauge invariant (see : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_fixing). In this problem, you need to find $A_r,A_{\theta}$ from the equation $B=\nabla \times \textbf{A}$ expressed in cylindrical coordinates. Since the functions $f(r,\theta)$, $\mu(r)$ are arbitrary I couldn't figure out what should be a good choice of gauge for this problem. I assumed that $A_r$ should contain the factor $F(r,\theta)$ and $A_{\theta}$ to be dependent on r only , it gave the desired result